# Confluence in Docker can't see PostgreSQL in Docker

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, networking, confluence

I'm trying to set up both Confluence and PostgreSQL in Docker.  I've got them both up and running on my fully up to date CentOS 6 machine, with volume-mapping to the host file system so I can back them up easily.  I can connect to PostgreSQL using pgAdmin from another machine just fine, and I can get into Confluence from a browser from that same machine.  So, basically, both apps seem to be running as expected inside their respective containers and are accessible to the outside world, which of course eliminates a whole bunch of possibilities for my issue.

And that issue is that Confluence can't talk to PostgreSQL during initial setup, which is necessary for it to function.  I'm getting connection failed errors (to be specific: "Can't reach database server or port : SQLState - 08001 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed").

PostgreSQL is using the default 5432 port, which of course is exposed, otherwise I wouldn't be able to connect to it via pgAdmin, and of course I know the ID/password I'm trying is correct for the same reason (and besides, if it was an auth problem I wouldn't expect to see this error message).  When I try to configure the database connection during Confluence's initial setup, I specify the IP address of the host machine, just like from pgAdmin on the other machine, but that doesn't work.  I also tried some things that I basically knew wouldn't work (0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost).

I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work.  Is there maybe some special method to specify the IP to a container from the same host machine, some nomenclature I'm not aware of?

At this point, I'm "okay" with Docker in terms of basic operations, but I'm far from an expert, so I'm a bit lost.  I'm also not a big-time *nix user generally, though I can *usually* fumble my way through most things... but any hints would be greatly appreciated because I'm at a loss right now otherwise.

Thanks,
Frank

EDIT 1: As requested by someone below, here's my pg_hba.conf file, minus comments:

```
    local   all             all                                     trust
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
    local   replication     all                                     trust
    host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

    host all all all md5
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of your pg_hba.conf file from postgres?

Comment: @RSloeserwij  Sure thing, see edit 1 in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

try changing the second line of the pg_hba.conf file to the following:

```
host    all    all    0.0.0.0/32    trust
```

this will cause PostgreSQL to start accepting calls from any source address. Since a docker container is technically not operating on localhost but on its own ip, the current configuration causes PostgreSQL to block any connections to it.

Also check if confluence is searching for the database on localhost. If that is the case change that to the ip of the hostmachine within the docker network.

Comment: Thanks for that attempt (it took me a few days to even try it due to a power loss at home) but once I did, it, unfortunately, doesn't change anything.  I can still reach it from pgAdmin on another machine, but not from Confluence in another container on the same machine. I also tried samehost and samenet, but they didn't work either.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: i've added another possible issue, could you try that out for me?

Comment: Hi... yes, I've tried IP address already actually, IP of the host machine, since that's how I'm accessing all the other containers I have running (on different ports obviously).  I've also tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 and even 0.0.0.0 (because I saw that in the config file and wasn't sure if that was some Docker trick I wasn't aware of). None work. My working theory is that since all my containers use the same IP, that of the host machine, it's like a bad loopback. Thinking maybe I have to give the Postgres container its own IP, but not sure how to do that (if that's even possible).

Comment: you docker daemon should have an internal network, visible through ifconfig called docker. All your containers and the host machine should have an ip in the range 172.17.0.0/24 in there.

Answer (score 1):

Success!  The solution was to create a custom network and then use the image name in the connection string to PostreSQL container from Confluence container.  In other words, I ran this:

docker network create -d bridge docker-net

Then, on both of the docker run commands for the PostgreSQL and Confluence containers, I added:

--network=docker-net

That way, when I ran through the Confluence configuration wizard, when it asked for the hostname for the PostgreSQL server, I used postgres (the name I gave the container) rather than an IP address or actual hostname.  Docker makes that work thanks to the custom network.  This also leaves the containers available via the IP of the host machine, so for example I can still connect to PostgreSQL via 192.168.123.12:5432, and of course I can launch Confluence in the browser via 192.168.123.12:8080.

FYI, I didn't even have to alter the pg_hba.conf file, I just used the official PostgreSQL image (latest) as it was, which is ideal.

Thanks very much to RSloeserwij for the suggestions... while none of them proved to be the solution I needed, they did put me on the right track in the Docker docs, which, after some reading, led me to understand a few things I didn't before and figure out the config magic I needed.